# EMR - Sqoop import using hcatalog failing on EMR

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-emr, sqoop, hcatalog

I am using EMR - 6.4.0 (sqoop version 1.4.7 )
and  using oozie workflow to import data from postgres into hive partitions using hcatalog,data is getting loaded into the table and partitions are getting created but job fails with the following error

```
  Job commit failed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getTokenStrForm is not supported
    at com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.GlueMetastoreClientDelegate.getTokenStrForm(GlueMetastoreClientDelegate.java:1630)
    at com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSCatalogMetastoreClient.getTokenStrForm(AWSCatalogMetastoreClient.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient.invoke(HiveClientCache.java:590)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.getTokenStrForm(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.cancelDelegationTokens(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:1012)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.commitJob(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.handleJobCommit(CommitterEventHandler.java:286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.run(CommitterEventHandler.java:238)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I dont see any mention about this error or limitation  in EMR docs or in web.

Importing directly to table directory is working but wanted to know why hcatalog option couldn't be used

Comment: I suggest reaching out to EMR support since this is a Glue error